# What is the correct HTML tag for GeoLocation information/coordinates?

Tags: html, gps

The same way that there is `address` for street names and places is there some HTML tag that is indicated, semantic to wrap GPS coordinates or other GeoLocation information?

Or alternative is there a microformat for this? I saw some ideas out there [(1)](http://microformats.org/wiki/h-geo), [(2)](https://saddamazad.com/2015/11/google-maps-schema-org-markup/).

The practical example is in a list of items, let us say restaurants for example, how to have the GPS coordinates in a semantic, SEO smart tag.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>Johns restaurant</p>
        <address>
            Avenue 24<br>
            Downstreet<br>
            GPS: 100.00, 100.00
        </address>
    </li>
    <li>
        etc...
    </li>
</ul>
```

(maybe address is the answer in the end?)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the geo URI scheme name.

Example:

```
<a href="geo:41.2051487,-8.6649087;">Location</a>
```

More information see [IETF RFC 5870](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5870), specially the [Section 6.2. Hyperlink](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5870#section-6.2).

But there also a [GEO microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/geo).

Example:

```
<div class="geo">Location: 
   <span class="latitude">41.2051487</span>, 
   <span class="longitude">-8.6649087</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps clearing things a bit!